# How to track different performance improvements in different components of an application that might overlap?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, profiling, performance

So this is kind of a general question.Here is the problem:

I am currently working on a project along with 5 other people. We have all been assigned different performance tuning projects within an application (Java EE). However we all need to report how much of an improvement did we really achieve compared to our original component. Now if we are all checking in our code at various times, how do we necessarily track our own individual performance improvements in a given time?

I was thinking perhaps put flags in our code and keep track of all my code changes, but I feel like that would be too messy since  for example let's say an improvement would be like to utilize primitive data types instead of like Integer Objects, but this improvement might cross over to someone else's work.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Define performance improvement, is it timing? If so, may be timings before your component & after your component execution will provide high level info.

Comment: performance improvement as in -> memory reduction

Comment: I think it is better not to have artificial boundaries on responsibilities like that. Rather performance issues should be treated just as if they were bugs (which everyone will make). Everyone should be welcome to help find them, wherever they are, and then the responsibility of fixing them should go to the specific code's "owner".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for any performance improvement (be it better speed or lower ram), you should setup a testbed. If you cannot do it with unit tests, if it is a web application, try writing a JMeter test plan.

Run the test, always with same parameters (same JVM, started with same max heap, same number of thread in the test etc...).

Run it on the unoptimized application, and derive some benchmark data using some tool (there are many in the jdk, jvisualvm is easy but needs human interaction, jmap can be automated).

Suppose that it uses 500Mb of ram and 10 minutes to complete the test plan on the unoptimized version.

Running these tests, each developer can test if the modification he made is making the situation better, not changing anything, or even making it worse, before checking it in source versioning.

Since you check in code, you know who checked in which modification, and you can (using git, svn, or any other modern source versioning system) checkout a specific version.

Running the test against various versions, you can see if you are progressing in the task of lowering ram consumption, or time, or whatever metric ... and as a side effect also who contributed to it which numbers.

You could even make it automatic using a continuous integration tool, like Hudson, Jenkins etc.. Instructing it to checkout, compile, deploy, run tests, collect data, send a mail with who committed what and how numbers changed, but having a super-computer telling who the good guys are .... is not the best for team morale.

Comment: Beautiful answer. Personally I disagree with the last statement about the impact of performance reporting on the team morale, but that's a completely different discussion :-).

Comment: Hi Tony, I agree, but it depends. I love continuous integration, and love that it's possible to track down who broke the build and who fixed the most, but it all depends on how the team is. Since here we are explicitly talking about tracking individuals performance on very strict numerical basis. Having one person never making it, or worse having one that is always making far better than others, can sometimes be detrimental. I would first look at the report as a manager, and then decide whether to make it automatically public or how to "tune" the group myself.

Comment: I tried using jmap but I realized that our project uses a different jdk. Are there other tools available? or Is it possible to tweak Jmap or VisualVm to work with our application?